# Android - Crashlytics automatically send Error Reports when the device goes online without having to open the application?

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I used CrashLytics to make an application that I made send error reports whenever my users encounter them. The application is wonderful and works really great. I am able to get the reports on the dashboard almost immediately after the application crashed and it includes the line number and the exception that was encountered, it was like I was looking at the LogCat itself.

I noticed that it doesn't send the error report when the device is offline which is pretty understandable. I then turned the WiFi on, waited for ~3 minutes, refreshed my dashboard, and I was hoping that the error report would send automatically. However, I didn't get any new reports on my dashboard. I had to open the application again (while the device was online), wait for a minute or two, then I saw the new errors.

I think the errors are saved, put on queue if the device is offline. Then once the app is opened once more and then the device is online, those errors are sent.

However, I want to make the experience more seamless for the user and just automatically send the error logs once the user's device goes online.

I checked the Android Docs of CrashLytics, but I didn't find any examples that did what I wanted to achieve.

Is there anything I can do to automate CrashLytics to send the Errors as soon as the device goes online? Maybe something in the declaration or through a NetworkReceiver class that would call a function of the library once the receiver knows the device is online?

I feel like I'm overlooking something simple or I may have missed out on something they said in the website.